# addr2line not show line number and filename with newer GCC

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gcc, backtrace

### Problem

I'm in Linux, would like to use `backtrace()` function to capture segmentation fault (i.e. the SIGSEGV signal). The following C code with GCC-5.4 and addr2line can show line number and filename, but GCC 7.5 or GCC 9.3 can't get that information. How can I let `addr2line` show line number and file name with GCC 7.5 or 9.3?

### Code

`x.c`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>     /* for signal */
#include <execinfo.h>   /* for backtrace() */
 

#define BACKTRACE_SIZE   16

void dump(void)
{
    int j, nptrs;
    void *buffer[BACKTRACE_SIZE];
    char **strings;
    
    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, BACKTRACE_SIZE);
    
    printf("backtrace() returned %d addresses\n", nptrs);

    strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
    if (strings == NULL) {
        perror("backtrace_symbols");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < nptrs; j++)
        printf("  [%02d] %s\n", j, strings[j]);

    free(strings);
}

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    
#if 0
    char buff[64] = {0x00};
        
    sprintf(buff,"cat /proc/%d/maps", getpid());
        
    system((const char*) buff);
#endif

    printf("\n=========>>>catch signal %d <<<=========\n", signo);
    
    printf("Dump stack start...\n");
    dump();
    printf("Dump stack end...\n");

    signal(signo, SIG_DFL); /* restore to default signal */
    raise(signo);           /* resend signal */
}

int add1(int num)
{
    int ret = 0x00;
    int *pTemp = NULL;
    *pTemp = 0x01;  /* this will cause an segment fault, cause the application crash */
    ret = num + *pTemp;
    return ret;
}

int add(int num)
{
    int ret = 0x00;
    ret = add1(num);
    return ret;
}
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sum = 0x00;

    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);

    sum = add(sum);

    printf(" sum = %d \n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

### Expected and actual result

**Expected**:

```
zz@localhost$ addr2line -f -p -s -e ./a.out 0x400c46
add1 at x.c:60
```

**Actual**

```
zz@localhost$ addr2line -f -p -s -e ./a.out 0x55baa10213f1
?? ??:0
```

### Steps to reproduce

#### gcc 5.4

1. compile with `-g -rdynamic`

```sh
zz@localhost$ gcc -g -rdynamic x.c
```

2. Execute

```
zz@localhost$ ./a.out 

=========>>>catch signal 11 <<<=========
Dump stack start...
backtrace() returned 8 addresses
  [00] ./a.out(dump+0x2e) [0x400b04]
  [01] ./a.out(signal_handler+0x2e) [0x400c06]
  [02] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x354c0) [0x7f38179954c0]
  [03] ./a.out(add1+0x1a) [0x400c46]
  [04] ./a.out(add+0x1c) [0x400c7b]
  [05] ./a.out(main+0x2f) [0x400cb2]
  [06] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f3817980840]
  [07] ./a.out(_start+0x29) [0x400a09]
Dump stack end...
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

3. Query address for `add1` function, i.e. `0x400c46` in `[03] ./a.out(add1+0x1a) [0x400c46]`.

```
zz@localhost$ addr2line -f -p -s -e ./a.out 0x400c46
add1 at x.c:60
zz@localhost$ 
zz@localhost$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

#### gcc 7.5/9.3

Steps are same as gcc 5.4, but with different outputs:

```
zz@localhost$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

zz@localhost$ gcc -g -rdynamic x.c
zz@localhost$ ./a.out 

=========>>>catch signal 11 <<<=========
Dump stack start...
backtrace() returned 8 addresses
  [00] ./a.out(dump+0x32) [0x55baa102129b]
  [01] ./a.out(signal_handler+0x36) [0x55baa10213ab]
  [02] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210) [0x7f4808e78210]
  [03] ./a.out(add1+0x1e) [0x55baa10213f1]
  [04] ./a.out(add+0x20) [0x55baa102142a]
  [05] ./a.out(main+0x35) [0x55baa1021467]
  [06] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f4808e590b3]
  [07] ./a.out(_start+0x2e) [0x55baa10211ae]
Dump stack end...
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out
zz@localhost$ addr2line -f -p -s -e ./a.out 0x55baa10213f1
?? ??:0
```

Comment: What version of addr2line do you use?

Comment: @ssbssa I'm using addr2line `2.34`.

Comment: Now I see the problem, the newer executable has ASLR enabled, that's why the addresses are so high (`0x55baa10213f1`). So the debug information in the executable uses a different base address than the actual running executable.

Comment: @ssbssa I'm now even more confused.. How can I disable ASLR temporarily for gcc? I tried `gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack` but not working.

Comment: Try compiling with `-no-pie`.

Comment: @ssbssa Thank you! Actually before asking this question I tried with adding `-fno-pie` but didn't work. Now with full command ` gcc -g -rdynamic -no-pie x.c` it works!